# What's the best way to store images inside my React App (NodeJS, Express, MongoDB)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload

Hello and thanks for your answers!

I´m creating a webapp (React, NodeJS, Express, MongoDB) where my users can upload products and i was wondering where it´s the best place to store the images. I know i can store them directly in the `/public/` folder of my project and save the url into MongoDB, but i also know i can use services like AWS Storages.

Considering i´m not going to host my app in AWS, is it worth it to have my image files in a separate service? I´m not expecting to have an huge app but i´m expecting around 200/300 images, having 300 images in my `/public/` folder affects my app performance at the moment of the render?

Thank you so much again, have a good day.

Comment: It is definitely not recommended to store files in your project location (e.g. depending on how you deploy your app, they may be deleted). I guess one of the recommended approaches is to use an external service like AWS S3.

Comment: For such small amount of images(200-300 = 100MB?)  you can even store in mongoDB for image files <16MB or use gridFS for files bigger then 16MB , but afcourse very depends on your use case , in general the  recommended way is to offload such blob data to external systems like AWS S3 buckets or your own storage system and store only the references in mongoDB with the assumption that your web system will grow one day ...